# Victory.js change fontSize of data of VictoryLegend, not the title but the data

Tags: reactjs, victory-charts

```
<VictoryLegend
        x={100}
        y={10}
        title="Legend"
        centerTitle
        orientation='horizontal'
        gutter={20}
        style={{title: {fontSize: 30}}}
        data={legendData}
        labels={<legendLabel/>}
      />
const legendLabel = (props) => {
    return (
      <text
        fontSize={24}
        textAnchor="middle"
        dominantBaseline="central"
        {...props}
      >
        {props.text}
      </text>
    );
  };
 const legendData= [
    {name: "Difficulty", symbol: {fill: "green", type: "square", size: 14}},
    {name: "Enjoyment", symbol: {fill: "blue", type: "square", size: 14}}
  ]
```

So it seems that the component legendLabel doesn't get recognized, what am I doing wrong here? As it says in the title, I'm looking to change the fontSize or size of the data in the legend, not the title, I already did that.

Answer (score 0):

Update `fontSize` of the `labels` in `style`.

```
<VictoryLegend
        x={100}
        y={10}
        title="Legend"
        centerTitle
        orientation='horizontal'
        gutter={20}
        style={{title: {fontSize: 30}, labels: { fontSize: 13} }}
        data={legendData}
        labels={<legendLabel/>}
      />
```